# Why does Firebase show error that cant resolve rxjs/observable

Tags: javascript, angular, web

[image]

So in the command prompt I am getting this error I tried several things but it didn't helped me. So what should i do now

Comment: Hi it seems that those dependencies are currently not installed in your project or that your build tool can't find them, you might need to `npm install` or `yarn`

Comment: It seems that your package.json has package but it does not installed on your system. so please try to install bower install/ npm install/ yarn install

Comment: i did npm install but still its showing all the errors

Comment: Actually its searching in C:/Users/Abhishek/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js but inside Abhishek i dont have node_modules biut i have several others projects